# How to get UISearchBar baseline position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I'm subclassing UISearchBar and I want to add label that it's baseline will be aligned with UISearchTextField's baseline. I extract UISearchTextField from the searchbar and try to setup constraints like this:

```
- (void)addConstraintToBottomLabel {
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *baseline = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.searchTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self addConstraints:@[leading, trailing, baseline]];
}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

As you see, the labels aren't aligned.

For testing in constraints works well in other situation I align bottomLabel's baseline with textField's bottom and it works great. So where could be the problem?

Comment: Hello 
can you please tell me what you want to do because still i don't understand this questions !

Comment: Ok I simplified the question.